# Laravel 5 autocomplete route Input class

Tags: javascript, php, laravel-5

I have autocomplete script in laravel 5, but I have problem with getting value from search field.

My route code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;

Route::get('access_users/getdata',function(){

    **$query = Input::get('last_name');**

    $data = User::where('last_name','like','%'.$query.'%')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

return $data;
```

});

Problem is, $query is empty everytime.

HTML code:

```
 {!! Form::text('last_name', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => trans('strings.full_name')]) !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

My wrong, input does not take value from html input but from url.

Answer (score 0):

input is laravel 4 laravel 5 you must ask to the request facade

```
Route::get('access_users/getdata',function(){

    $query = Request::input('last_name');

    $data = User::where('last_name','like','%'.$query.'%')
    ->take(10)
    ->get();

return $data;
```

source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/requests#obtaining-a-request-instance